# Solve for $x$ in $\log_2{\frac{2-x}{3}} \le \log_2{\frac{2+6}{3}}$

Tags: calculus

$\log_2{\frac{2-x}{3}} \le \log_2{\frac{2+6}{3}}$

I did:

$$\log_2{\frac{2-x}{3}} \le \log_2{\frac{2+6}{3}} \\\Leftrightarrow \log_2{\frac{2-x}{3}} \le \log_2{\frac{8}{3}}\\
\Leftrightarrow \log_2(\frac{2-x}{3}) \le 3 - \log_2(3) \\
\Leftrightarrow \log_2(\frac{2-x}{3}) + \log_2(3)\le 3 \\
\Leftrightarrow \log_2(\frac{3(2-x)}{3}) \le 3 \\
\Leftrightarrow \log_2(2-x) \le \log_2(8) \\
\Leftrightarrow 2-x \le 8 \\
\Leftrightarrow -x \le 6 \\
\Leftrightarrow x \ge -6$$

So the solution is $[-6;+\infty[$

But my book says the solution is $[-6;2[$. What did I do wrong? How do I solve this correctly?

Comment: The left hand side isn't even defined for large $x$.

Comment: You forgot to use the fact that $\dfrac{2-x}{3}>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logarithms are only defined for positive numbers, hence you must have $2 - x > 0$, i.e. $x < 2$. Also note that a much simpler solution is to just note that since logarithms are strictly increasing functions,
$$\log_2\frac{2 - x}{3} \leq \log_2\frac{8}{3}$$
holds if and only if the left side is defined and
$$\frac{2 - x}{3} \leq \frac{8}{3}.$$